# jQuery is undefined in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

Working with laravel 5.4 on windows.

In scripts.blade file, I am calling all kinds of javascript files that I downloaded for Admin LTE bootstrap template.

The code:

```
<script>
window.Laravel = {!! json_encode(['csrfToken' => csrf_token()]) !!};
</script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8b42d9ab76.js"></script>
<script src="/js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
$.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>

<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="admin-theme/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="admin-theme/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"> </script>
<!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="admin-theme/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="admin-theme/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
<script src="admin-theme/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="admin-theme/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="admin-theme/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
<script src="admin-theme/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="admin-theme/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="admin-theme/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="admin-theme/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<script src="admin-theme/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="admin-theme/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
```

In firebug I get all these errors:
[image]

Any idea why this is happenning?

Comment: it seems to be you are not include jquery in page.try to add this tag before all script tag 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: I don't know why you're getting downvoted. I can reproduce this issue on 5.4 upgrading from 5.3. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the core `jquery.min.js` in your `script` tag. I cannot see it. You should include it before any of the js files.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing the jQuery library! Include it to fulfil the dependencies. You can download from [here](http://jquery.com/download/)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because your javaScript Files are not loaded especially Jquery.

use :

```
<script src="{{asset('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Never directly give js links in the blade templating engine.

You should always use the blade style of embedding scripts in your page:

Scripts can be used in the following two ways:

**Method 1**:

```
<script src="{{asset('admin-theme/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js')}}"></script>
```

**Method 2**: Preferred way

```
{{Html::script('admin-theme/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js')}}
```

Comment: This call loads the jquery: 
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
because app.js calls bootstrap.js that has this code:

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

As far as I understand this is the way Laravel loads jQuery

Comment: open the dev console of the browser and check if jquery has actually been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are requiring jQuery before the the AdminLTE libraries

Comment: Thank you all, but I think you are all missing the point that I am using laravel 5.4 with mix, and the call to mix('js/app.js') should include jquery automatically.